# Getting list of lists in Hibernate

Tags: java, hibernate

In my project I have two entities: `Race` and `RaceDriver`, which has-a `Race` in it:

```
class RaceDriver {

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "race", nullable = false)
    private Race race;
    ...
    @Column(name = "starting_nr")
    private Integer startingNr;
    ...
    @Column(name = "disqualified", nullable = false)
    private boolean disqualified;
}
```

Now, what I wanted is to get the list of the `startingNr`s of the `disqualified` `RaceDriver`s in a `Race`, which looked like this:

```
public List<Integer> findDisqualifiedDriversStartingNumbers(Integer raceId) {
    ProjectionList projection = Projections.projectionList()
        .add(Projections.property("startingNr").as("startingNr"));

    return getSession()
        .createCriteria(RaceDriver.class)
        .setProjection(projection)
        .add(Restrictions.eq("race.id", raceId))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("disqualified", true))
        .list();
}
```

The thing is that now I need the same, but **for the few** `Races`. How can I achieve this without making a separate DAO calls? Because I've heard that it is better to make as much as possible in a single database call.

My idea is to simply get the list of the drivers which are disqualified in the given races, and then parse it in the Java code, which I think will require few loops, and make some map of disqualified `RaceDriver`'s starting numbers, where the key would be `Race.id`.

The DAO attempt looks like that:

```
public List<RaceDriver> findDisqualifiedDriversInRaces(List<Integer> raceIds) {

    return getSession()
        .createCriteria(RaceDriver.class)
        .add(Restrictions.in("race.id", raceIds))
        .add(Restrictions.eq("disqualified", true))
        .list();
}
```

The problem is that I will get that big objects, instead of some map or list of the only data I need (`startingNr` and `race.id`).

So the question is - can I do it somehow using only Hibernate?

Comment: Have you tried [`ResultTransformer`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html)

Comment: After your comment I've tried `AliasToEntityMapResultTransformer`, however it returned me a List of HashMaps containing (key->value) for example two entries: `startingNr -> 9` and `raceId -> 2`... and unfortunately I still have no idea how could I map it to a List of HashMaps with `raceId` as a key, and a List of `startingNr` (of disqualified drivers) as a value...

Comment: can you post your `Race` class also.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Personally I would use the solution in plain java because it'll be more clear for any developer supporting your code in the future.

Answering the question "can it be done via Hibernate?": yes, it can be, [ResultTransformer](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.3/api/org/hibernate/transform/ResultTransformer.html) is the right way, especially if map-of-lists conversion is required more than once in your program. There is no standard transformer for your needs but you can write your own one:

```
public class MapOfListsResultTransformer<K, V> extends BasicTransformerAdapter {

    public List transformList(List collection) {
        final Map<K, List<V>> map = new HashMap<>();

        for (Object object : collection) {
            final Object[] objects = (Object[]) object;
            final K key = (K) objects[0];
            final V value = (V) objects[1];
            if (!map.containsKey(key)) {
                final List<V> list = new ArrayList<V>();
                list.add(value);
                map.put(key, list);
            } else {
                map.get(key).add(value);
            }
        }

        return Arrays.asList(map);
    }
}
```

And its usage is the following:

```
public Map<Integer, List<Integer>> findDisqualifiedDriversInRaces(List<Integer> raceIds) {
    ProjectionList projection = Projections.projectionList()
            .add(Projections.property("race.id").as("race.id"))
            .add(Projections.property("startingNr").as("startingNr"));

    return (Map<Integer, List<Integer>>) getSession()
            .createCriteria(RaceDriver.class)
            .setProjection(projection)
            .add(Restrictions.in("race.id", raceIds))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("disqualified", true))
            .setResultTransformer(new MapOfListsResultTransformer<Integer, Integer>())
            .uniqueResult();
}
```

Comment: This is a really wonderful solution, looks like I've been looking exactly for that. I think you won... :) thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

You'll want to create a `Query` with hibernate that has two WHERE conditions.

```
@PersistenceContext protected EntityManager em;

List<Integer> raceIds = Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3);
Query query = em.createQuery("FROM RaceDriver r WHERE r.raceId IN (:raceIds) AND r.disqualified = true");
query.setParameter("raceIds", raceIds);
List<RaceDriver> drivers = query.getResultList();
```

This will return a list of disqualified drivers within the raceIds that you've provided.

**Update**

After getting `List<RaceDriver>` you can for loop on `drivers` and make List of HashMaps with `raceId` as a key, and a List of `startingNr` (of disqualified drivers) as a value.

```
HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>> startingNrHashMap=new...;

for(RaceDriver driver:drivers)
{
  List<Integer> strNr = new ArrayList<Integer>();
  if(startingNrHashMap.containsKey(driver.race.raceid))
  {
    //if race id is already present in hash map then

    strNr = startingNrHashMap.get(driver.race.raceid);
    strNr.add(driver.startingNr);
    startingNrHashMap.put(driver.race.raceid,strNr);
  }
  else
  {
    // if race id is NOT present in hash map
    strNr.add(driver.startingNr);
    startingNrHashMap.put(driver.race.raceid,strNr);
  }
 strNr =null;
}
```

Comment: If you are getting `List of drivers` then by using code in Update you will get HashMaps as you required.

Comment: Heh, the funny thing is I did it this way before you answered... ;) because it had do be done. However I am curious of the possible better way of doing this; and my question was is that possible doing **with Hibernate only**. So it's not really answering my question, however thank you for your time and a solution! It could be helpful to someone.

Comment: @EelLee :) No problem you are the winner,No need of such explanation..okey :)

Comment: @Amogh well, it solves the problem (however in a different way) and got its upvotes... so why not ;-)

Answer (score 1):

This is how I did it:

#### DAO method:

```
public List<RaceDriver> findDisqualifiedDriversInRaces(List<Integer> raceIds) {
    if (!raceIds.isEmpty()) { // it will crash if the list will have no elements!
        return getSession()
            .createCriteria(RaceDriver.class)
            .add(Restrictions.in("race.id", raceIds))
            .add(Restrictions.eq("disqualified", true))
            .list();
    }
    return Collections.emptyList();
}
```

Then to extract from it what I wanted, I created an auxiliary method:

```
// key = race.id, value = list of disqualified raceDrivers' starting numbers

private HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> extractStartingNumbersToMap(List<RaceDriver> disqualifiedDrivers) {
    HashMap<Integer, List<Integer>> disqualifiedDriversMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (RaceDriver raceDriver : disqualifiedDrivers) {
        Integer raceId = raceDriver.getRace().getId();

        if (!disqualifiedDriversMap.containsKey(raceId)) {
            disqualifiedDriversMap.put(raceId, new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(raceDriver.getStartingNr())));
        } else {
            disqualifiedDriversMap.get(raceId).add(raceDriver.getStartingNr());
        }
    }
    return disqualifiedDriversMap;
}
```

I did it before Mark T has answered, as you can see it's very similar. However I'm posting it, as it could be helpful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

I asked the same kind of question, Its about NHibernate and .NET MVC but you can get idea of DAO and `ResultTransformer`

[Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12720470/fetch-single-property-in-object-from-database)

Comment: Yeah I've been using `AliasToBeanResultTransformer`, but would it map the data to the proper collection? To use some DTO containing fields `race.id` and `List<Integer> startingNumbers`? Maybe worth trying, I'll try something with that. Thanks for the hint.